# BackgroundWorker for YouTube DirectUpload in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, upload, youtube, backgroundworker

I'm trying to implement a direct upload of videos on my server to YouTube.  When a user adds a video, it gets copied to YouTube.

The user action of adding the video should begin the upload process, which could take a while.  The form, even an asynchronous form, should not sit there and wait for this to happen.  It should just begin and allow the user to move on, trusting that it is being taken care of in the background.

To allow this, I am attempting to use system.threading.backgroundworker.  My hope is that the process would begin, and the web app would move on.  It's not.  It's hanging, whether it's an asynchronous or full postback, and waiting for the upload to finish before returning and updating the lblmsg.text.

Is there a different way I should be going about this, so the user can initiate the upload procedure and not wait around for it to complete?  Here is my code so far:

```
Sub up_load(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler (worker.DoWork), AddressOf begin_upload

    'call this and move on?
    worker.RunWorkerAsync()

    lblmsg.Text = "Successfully initiated upload"

End Sub

Sub begin_upload(s As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
    Dim vidupload As New Video()

    vidupload.Title = "My Big Test Movie"
    vidupload.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    vidupload.Keywords = "church, jesus"
    vidupload.Description = "See the entire video"
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Downers Grove, IL")
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\users\greg\test3.asf", "video/x-ms-wmv")

    Dim createdVideo As Video = Request.Upload(vidupload)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for adding multithreading to your code. Given the code that you provided:

Add this import statement

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
```

And replace all backgroundworker logic with this simple statement:

```
    Dim uploadTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                       Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
                                                       Dim vidupload As New Video()

                                                       vidupload.Title = "My Big Test Movie"
                                                       vidupload.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
                                                       vidupload.Keywords = "church, jesus"
                                                       vidupload.Description = "See the entire video"
                                                       vidupload.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
                                                       vidupload.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Downers Grove, IL")
                                                       vidupload.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\users\greg\test3.asf", "video/x-ms-wmv")

                                                       Dim createdVideo As Video = request.Upload(vidupload)
                                                   End Sub)
```

Now you have the uploadTask uploading your video in the background and your UI thread will be free to process other code. It does get a bit more complicated if you want cancellation and progress reporting, but the link at the top should get you started.

Comment: Thank you!  This is definitely a step closer.  It starts the process in the background and returns, but I'm getting a "Failed, upload aborted" after a few minutes on the YouTube side.  Will it keep the process alive until it completes, or do I have to worry about recycling or timeouts or something?

Comment: Update: Tried to use the LongRunning option when creating the task, still aborted and failed on a 75MB file upload.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not aware of any default timeouts so I believe the youtube API is to blame for that. The TPL was designed with simplicity in mind so that you wouldn't have to worry about managing threads and such.